# Run Gazelle in dry-run or warn mode

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-gazelle

### Context

Is there a way to have gazelle run in dry-run mode?

I'd like to create a CI job that runs gazelle with dry-run and fails if gazelle finds any changes.

Something like this

```sh
$ bazel run //:gazelle --dry-run || exit 1
```

### Different Approach

I think this can be accomplished by running the command and seeing if git finds any changes, but I would prefer a non-git approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-mode diff` flag should work perfectly here when running in `update` mode (the default):

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#fix-and-update

```
$ bazel run //:gazelle -- -mode diff || exit 1
```

I'm working on making a bazel test that would enforce this, will share if/when I get something working!

Comment: I ended up going with something similar using `-mode diff`